# Dart 2 and parsing json

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Im trying to parse json into a list of Products using Dart 2 for web.

I have the following Class:

```
class Product {

  final String Problem;

  final String Owner;

  final String Description;

  const Product({
    this.Problem, 
    this.Owner,
    this.Description,
  });


  factory Product.parse(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    print(json);
    return new Product(
      Problem: json["Problem"],
      Owner: json["Owner"],
      Description: json["Description"]
    );
  }
}
```

And I am trying to parse this using:

```
Stream<Product> getProducts() async* {
    final payload = await HttpRequest.getString("products.json");
    print(payload);
    //var _json = (json.decode(payload));
    print("break");
    var list = json.decode(payload);
    print(list);
    //print(list);
    final productList = (json.decode(payload) as List).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  }
```

However this fails with this error:

> EXCEPTION: Type '_JsonMap' is not a subtype of expected type
>   'List'.

I can see that I have a `list[Symbol(_original)]` when I debug, but when I try to evaluate this, I returns as undefined.

I also tried

- `List list = json.decode(payload) as List;`
- `List<dynamic> list = json.decode(payload);`
- `List<dynamic> list = json.decode(payload) as List<dynamic>;`
- `var list = (json.decode(payload)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();`
- `var list = (json.decode(payload)).cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();`

but get the same error.

### Json

```
{
    "Product_One": {
        "Owner": "test",
        "Description": "test description",
        "Theme_Objective": "test objective",
        "Technical_details": "test technical details",
        "Problem": "test",
        "Solution": "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: So, based on your JSON payload, the top-level element is a `Map`.

i.e. `"Product_One"` is a key. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON does not contain any list, it's all maps. 
When you try to cast a `Map` to `List`, it has to fail since maps are not lists.

Maybe you want to do:

```
final productList = (jsonDecode(payload) as Map).values.toList();
```

This gives you a list of the product maps, without the names that you don't appear to be using anyway.