# Parse complex JSON from API for ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and dart, and I'm just trying to figure it out how to properly parse a complex JSON Object that I receive from an API.
The json is something like this

```
{
  "-MVM7-vKVzldY0DatkPz": {
    "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVM7JJa5mfrnoMC_mJn": {
    "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVM7peXBlw6jE7_hsxD": {
  "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVM8KXNA2SMgZZTvQVb": {
  "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVMB8yGXBIZb3BbQT3s": {
     "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  }
}
```

I made a function to parse the data, something like this

```
  Future<List<RSVP>> _fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get(URL);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return jsonResponse.map((data) => new Data.fromJson(data)).toList();      
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Failed to load json");
    }
  }
```

And a class

```
class Data {
  final String field1;
  final String field2;
  final String field3;
  final String field4;
  final String field5;
  final String field5;  
  final String field7;

  Data({this.field1 ,.... });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      field1:json['value']['field1'],
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

But when I try to run it I receive this
[image]

I know that is something related to how I parse the json but I can't figure it out how to parse a such a json

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50446036/8213910)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try this aswell

Answer (score 0):

json.decode(response.body) seems to return a Map not a List.

Try to create a list from your jsonResponse such as:

```
final jsonResponse = List.from(json.decode(response.body).values)
```

And then map over it and remove the ['value'] key in your Data.fromJson factory.

```
return jsonResponse.map((item) => Data.fromJson(item as Map<String, String>))
```

There is a Dart [package](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) easing the process of serialization/deserialization from and to JSON.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'll try to use this solution, but as I can understand, using List.from(json.decode(response.body).values) will give me only the values on each key, skipping the key itself. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly, I assumed from your example that the key was a unique key and it is not necessary to include it in the Data class.

Answer (score 0):

This code will works (if map has unique keys).

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:json_helpers/json_helpers.dart';

void main() {
  final map = _received.jsonMap((e) => Data.fromJson(e));
  for (final entry in map.entries) {
    print(entry.key);
    print(entry.value.field1);
  }
}

class Data {
  final String field1;

  Data({required this.field1});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      field1: json['field1'] as String,
    );
  }
}

final _received = '''
{
  "-MVM7-vKVzldY0DatkPz": {
    "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVM7JJa5mfrnoMC_mJn": {
    "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVM7peXBlw6jE7_hsxD": {
    "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVM8KXNA2SMgZZTvQVb": {
    "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  },
  "-MVMB8yGXBIZb3BbQT3s": {
    "field1": "val",
    "field2": "val ",
    "field4": "val ",
    "field5": "val ",
    "field6": "val ",
    "field7": "val"
  }
}''';
```

Output:

```
-MVM7-vKVzldY0DatkPz
val
-MVM7JJa5mfrnoMC_mJn
val
-MVM7peXBlw6jE7_hsxD
val
-MVM8KXNA2SMgZZTvQVb
val
-MVMB8yGXBIZb3BbQT3s
val
```